# How to fix black screen when trying to control a remote Lion machine with Apple Remote Desktop that is inactive at its Login Window?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

We are using Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) 3.5.2. on 10.6.8 to ARD control remote 10.7.5 Lion machines.

When the remote Lion machine is in its "inactive" stand and at the "Login Window", the result when controlling the remote computer is a completely black screen. This happens with both ARD versions 3.6.1 and 3.6.2

Only when the time updates, that tiny upper right rectangle of the screen is refreshed and correctly filled with time display. [image: Black Remote Desktop Control screen where upper right time rectangle is updated]

A workaround that refreshes a part of the screen, is to hover the pointer over the center of the screen to screen to refresh the part where login items appear.

Is there a workaround that refreshes the whole screen with less hassle, or even better how to fix?

Comment: facing the same situation, 10.6.4 and Remote Desktop 3.5.1 to remote a 10.7.4 Lion, I just blindly type my password and press enter to login

Answer (score 1):

try connecting via curtain mode

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the MTU on either of the machines and then try connecting again.  Lion doesn't work the same as Leopard or Snow Leopard did.  I had the same issue and the Mac Mini was upgraded from Leopard to Lion and that is when the issue surfaced and changing the MTU fixed the issue.  Not the ideal solution but a workaround nonetheless.

The MTU setting are under System Preferences → Network → Advanced → Ethernet.
Try changing it to 1460.